# How to enumerate all process and its relation windows title and process's name

Tags: c++

How to enumerate all process and its relation windows title and process's name

Comment: You do know that a process can have 0, 1 or more top-level windows?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand what you mean by "its relation". You can use `EnumProcesses` to enumerate all process IDs on the system, and you can use `EnumWindows` to enumerate all top-level windows in the system (and then use `GetWindowText` to retrieve the title). To correlate between the two, use `GetWindowThreadProcessId`.

Comment: I also get connect with product name ,it is possible to get this relation

Answer (score 1):

To enumerate windows:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct WindowInfo
{
    HWND m_hWnd;
    string m_title;
    WindowInfo(HWND hwnd, string title) : m_hWnd(hwnd), m_title(title) {}
};
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam)
{
    vector<WindowInfo*> & windows = *(vector<WindowInfo*>*)lParam;
    char title[256];
    GetWindowTextA(hwnd, title, 256);
    windows.push_back(new WindowInfo(hwnd,title));
    return TRUE;
}
int main() 
{
    vector<WindowInfo*> windows;
    BOOL ret = EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM) &windows);
    if ( ret ) 
    {
        //windows have windowinfo of all enumerated windows
    }        
}
```

Comment: I also get connect with product name ,it is possible to get this relation